# MappingIterator.readAll() generates a list 2 or 3 times bigger than its-self

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file to a pojo.  To do this I am using jackson-dataformat-csv.  I am testing the scalablity of my program and while time does not seem to be an issue the memory it uses is.  I am using just over a million records in a csv to parse into my pojos.  The problem is the server that will have this running on will have about 1.5GB ram and so far I have found that it is using almost 2GB at just over a million records. My problem is when I use this:

```
 MappingIterator<T> objects = csvMapper.readerFor(pojoClass).with(csvSchema).readValues(csvFile);
 List<T> list = objects.readAll();
```

the list I get back is almost 2GB.  When I create a list of a million pojos I use almost no memory.  I am creating that list like this:

```
    List<Pojo> pojos = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        Pojo newPojo= getNewPojo();
        pojos.add(newPojo);
    }
```

I am not sure why the first list I get back is so large when I can create a different list with the same number of objects just a different way of putting them there and have that list so small.  Please let me know if I am doing something wrong and how I can fix this issue I am having. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the library you are using, but if you can't find a solution maybe try [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read your pojos iteratively?

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
//...configure the parser

CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(parserSettings); 
for (Pojo address : routines.iterate(Pojo.class, csvFile, "UTF-8")) {
    //process your bean
}
```

Hope this helps, I recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051534/univocity-how-to-return-one-bean-per-row-using-iterator-style/38062722#38062722).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)